# How to add data from a form into JSON array in angular 4?

Tags: json, angular

Here i have an HTML code('signup.component.html'). It collects data from the user. I want to add these data dynamically into a JSON array.

```
<div class="signup" *ngIf="!name; else forminfo">
    <form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="addPost(rForm.value)" name="myForm">
         <div class="form-container">
             <div class="row columns">
                 <h1>Signup</h1>
                 <label>First Name
                     <input type="text" formControlName="fname">
                 </label>
                 <label>Last Name
                     <input type="text"  formControlName="lname">
                 </label>
                 <label>E-Mail
                     <input type="text"  formControlName="email" name="email">
                 </label>
                 <label>Password
                     <input type="password"  formControlName="password1" name="password1">
                 </label>
                 <label>Confirm Password
                     <input type="password"  formControlName="password2" name="password2">
                 </label>
                 <input type="submit" class="button expanded" value="Submit Form" [disabled]="!rForm.valid" (click)="validateEmail()" >
             </div>
         </div>
     </form>
 </div>
```

The following is my typescript('signup.component.ts'). I have 'fname','lname','email' and 'password1'.
I want to store these data into a JSON array so that i want to access it later.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent {

    rForm: FormGroup;
    post:any;                     // A property for our submitted form
    lname:string = '';
    fname:string = '';
    email:string = '';
    password1:string = '';
    password2:string = '';
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
        this.rForm = fb.group({
            'fname' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
            'lname' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
            'email' :[null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])],
            'password1':[null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])],
            'password2':[null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])]
        });
    }
    addPost(post) {
        this.fname = post.fname;
        this.lname = post.lname;
        this.email = post.email;
        this.password1 = post.password1;
        this.password2 = post.password2;
    }
    validateEmail(){
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        }
        var password = document.forms["myForm"]["password1"].value;
        var confirmPassword = document.forms["myForm"]["password2"].value;
        if (password != confirmPassword) {
            alert("Passwords do not match.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive) it will clear your doubt about reactive angular forms

Comment: Do you wonder how you get the data from the form? In that case, just use `this.rForm.value()`

Answer (score 0):

The core meaning of Angular is two way data binding.

Q: What does that mean?

A: To simplify -> you have .html and .ts file. In html you have input (like username), if you start to type username in that input on .ts side object or variable is automatically updated. Second way is if you change that variable or object on .ts side then html will also be updated.

So in your case for input:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="fname">
```

I would add:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="fname" [(ngModel)]="firstName">
```

And on .ts side add:

```
firstName: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `html`

```
<form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="addPost()" name="myForm">
```

In your `ts`

```
 addPost() {

console.log(this.rForm.value);

  }
```